# How to reduce the number of loops of 555,179,505,439 to a practically feasible number and get the same results in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a program that will perform 555,179,505,439 loops to be used in my analysis. The goal of the analysis is to find the best volume ratio to determine whether a stock will increase/decrease in price or not after the volume of a certain day is greater/less than it's volume average over a certain number of days (2 to 200 day averages). I am wondering if there is a faster or simpler way to get the results using a different code? I attached the excel file. The code will take 2.11 years to run as it is. [Excel File](https://ufile.io/7t0bf)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String

StartTime = Timer

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

Dim Total_Rows_Compiled As Long

Total_Rows_Compiled = Worksheets("Compiled").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ReDim Date_Initial(2 To Total_Rows_Compiled) As Date
ReDim Date_Range(2 To Total_Rows_Compiled) As Date
ReDim Stock_Initial(2 To Total_Rows_Compiled) As String
ReDim Stock_Range(2 To Total_Rows_Compiled) As String

Worksheets("Compiled").Range("A2:B" & Total_Rows_Compiled).Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Volume Analysis").Range("A2:B" & Total_Rows_Compiled)

For i = 2 To Total_Rows_Compiled
    For j = 2 To Total_Rows_Compiled
        For k = 2 To 200
            If Worksheets("Compiled").Cells(i, 2) - Worksheets("Compiled").Cells(j, 2) >= -k And Worksheets("Compiled").Cells(i, 2) - Worksheets("Compiled").Cells(j, 2) < 0 And Worksheets("Compiled").Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets("Compiled").Cells(j, 1) Then
                Worksheets("Volume Analysis").Cells(i, k + 1) = (Worksheets("Compiled").Cells(i, 7) / (Worksheets("Volume Analysis").Cells(i, k + 1) + Worksheets("Compiled").Cells(i, 7)))*100
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
Next i

MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: The question you ask is not a programming question but more a mathematical or algorithm question I think. Therefore this might be the wrong place, we cannot tell you how to implement something.

Comment: It's really basic math though. It's just (volume of current date (i) / average volume of past (k) days). I don't think programmers will find a ratio hard to understand. I'm concerned about the loop construction instead of the math logic

Comment: You might get some improvement in speed if you read the range that you need for calculation into an array and calculate there and then write the array back into the sheet. So you only have on read before calc and one write after calc (which is slow). But that will probably not reduce years into minutes. I mean yes, it is basic math but still an algorithm and you ask for another algorithm ("*simpler way to get the results using a different code?*"). I mean using arrays is a technical question, but it is not a technical/programming question to find a better algorithm that's a math question.

Comment: R seems like the natural choice for this, rather than either VBA or Matlab

Comment: Sadly I have 0 knowledge on R. The learning curve is another issue.

Comment: This is a rather well-studied optimisation problem: using a tool like r or matlab, or even handcoded in c++ should yield the answer in sub-second timescales. Your best bet I think is to study those tools.

Comment: It's not that I used the wrong tool, the loop logic was inefficient. The loop I made was 40,000 times longer than it should be. I tried using matlab and it was also too long. Each time you double the number of loops, the computation times do not double, but instead, quadruples each time based on what I observed.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the range into an array for calculation should speed it up, because reading/writing operations to cells is slow. This way we reduce it to one read and one write operation. Accessing the array is much faster, but that can't do any magical things. That amount of calculations still needs its time, but maybe you get it down to some days instead of years.

```
'read into array
Dim Compiled() As Variant
Compiled = Worksheets("Compiled").Range("A1", "H" & Total_Rows_Compiled).Value
Dim Analysis() As Variant
Analysis = Worksheets("Volume Analysis").Range("A1", "GT" & Total_Rows_Compiled).Value


For i = 2 To Total_Rows_Compiled
    For j = 2 To Total_Rows_Compiled
        For k = 2 To 200
            If Compiled(i, 2) - Compiled(j, 2) >= -k And Compiled(i, 2) - Compiled(j, 2) < 0 And Compiled(i, 1) = Compiled(j, 1) Then
                Analysis(i, k + 1) = Analysis(i, k + 1) + Compiled(i, 7)
            End If
            DoEvents 'don't let Excel unresponsive 
        Next k
    Next j
Next i

'write back
Worksheets("Volume Analysis").Range("A1", "GT" & Total_Rows_Compiled).Value = Analysis
```

If this improvement is not enough you should think about if Excel is the right tool for such a calculation (even if it is simple math, it is a lot of math). Excel VBA cannot multi-thread, therefore you cannot use the full power of your CPU. You might be much faster with a thread optimized math tool that can read data from Excel files (e.g. Matlab).

Comment: Thank you i'll check on this when I get home. I tried matlab, but the issue is the string values (stock codes). I might not know how to use it correctly since i'm a bit rusty on matlab although i'll try it also

Comment: @MarcSantos It is possible to handle the strings with Matlab too. I'm not very confident with Matlab at all, but I got much bigger calculations done there in an acceptable amount of time, where Excel would have taken years too. So if you got the chance to give Matlab a try, it would be worth.

Comment: I guess I might've used the wrong type of table. Thanks for the help. I I'll be using Matlab either way after I gather the data from these loops for linear programming optimization purposes

Answer (score 0):

PEH's approach with arrays is the way to go.

Also I think if you only want to look at each individual stock then sort the data on Stock and date. Then you should be able to eliminate or substantially reduce the second loop on rows compiled.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I actually want to find a general behavior in the stock market so I need as much data as possible. I need a robust trading system to select the relevant stocks before doing technical analysis which is tedious and time consuming if I would look at all charts

Comment: Yes: but your inner loop is only doing one stock ata time: you can speed this up a lot by sorting so that the inner loop only needs to look at a few hundred rows rather than 50000

Comment: That's true. Have to filter the stocks per stock code it would reduce the computation times significantly